# ntfs-3g Ignore case

Tags: linux, ntfs, fuse

I am mounting an ntfs filesystem on a Linux box using the fuse filesystem driver [ntfs-3g](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/).  I am then doing some operations on the filesystem (`git clone` to be precise) unmounting and attaching the filesystem to a Windows machine.

Here's the fun part.  The git clone creates two directories, `images/` and `Images/`, which because it's Linux git is fine.  Then when I attach that partition to the Windows VM and build, one of the tools blows up because it only sees the `Images/` directory.

Is there a way I can get ntfs-3g to work in case insensitive-yet-preserving mode, the same way Windows does?

I tried using `lowntfs-3g` but that makes everything lowercase which also doesn't work for me.

I have tried the mount option `windows_names` and it doesn't work:

```
[joxley@host /tmp/ntfs] sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o windows_names 
/dev/loop2p1 mntpoint
[joxley@host /tmp/ntfs] touch mntpoint/foo  
[joxley@host /tmp/ntfs] touch mntpoint/FOO
[joxley@host /tmp/ntfs] ls mntpoint
foo  FOO
```

I have also looked at [ciops](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/) but this creates lowercase filenames on the backing filesystem which leaves me in the same place as `lowntfs-3g`.

Comment: From [TFM](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#4)

Comment: Yes, I did RTFM and have already tried that.  It doesn't make things case sensitive.  Updating the question

Comment: Windows developers often assume their code will only run in case insensitive NTFS, when this is of course not true, and take inappropriate shortcuts. If possible, you should file a bug report with the tool's developer.

Answer (score 2):

```
lowntfs-3g -o windows_names -o ignore_case $@ /dev/sda3 /DATA/B
```

try to mount with terminal

and

```
/dev/sda3 /DATA/B  lowntfs-3g  ignore_case,windows_names 0 0
```

should be for fstab